# Bitcode is disabled in Facebook-iOS-SDK 4.37

Tags: bitcode

I have updated Facebook SDK 4.37, after updating the SDK I started seeing one compile time error to disable bitcode. I can't disable bitcode because I have watch kit app which really need to have bitcode enable. If anyone faced this issue and solution, please let me know.

The error that I am seeing is here:

> FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKLikeBoxView.o)' does not
>   contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode
>   setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or
>   disable bitcode for this target. file
>   FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit' for architecture arm64

I also posted the same thing on Developers page on Facebook. They are saying this is known and trying to fix.

Comment: I found out the issue was reported to Facebook 10 days ago and it has remained broken. This is unbelievable: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/189257625300905/?disable_redirect=0

Comment: I saw your comment. Is there any other way to send a message to the Facebook Developers Team apart from Support page where you already posted?

Comment: I am also unable to integrate this SDK until this issue is resolved. As of Oct 15, I don't see any updates from FB so far.

Comment: I already rolled back too.  `pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '4.36'` There is no point waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Facebook fixed the bug in 4.38

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4x/

Comment: this SDK wont work on Xcode 9 or lower, we need to switch to Xcode 10

Comment: introduced new issue with this sdk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983796/facebook-login-is-failing-sometimes-in-ios-sdk-4-38-0

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up integrating the facebook sdk without any bitcode issues. I went back and used 4.36 instead of 4.37. The download link I used is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads/). (I don't use cocoapods). Hopefully fb will eventually get around to releasing a stable version. But until then ill stick to 4.36.

Comment: Yes, 4.36 do not have any issue. I will wait for a few days for my release, if something fixed up by Facebook Team then I'll use it otherwise I will be roll back to 4.36